# Reducing the time it takes to calculate a scene before every frame when rendering an animation?

Tags: rendering

When rendering an animation in Blender, before every frame the scene is calculated and updated. ("updating Scene, updating Images, updating Lights, loading HDRI...") In my case this takes a considerable amount of time -currently around 10s per frame, which is more then the the actual shading for each frame usually takes. (cycles, on a GTX 3090 with a very low sample count for non-final animations) It really adds up.

When I play the scene in the viewport in solid mode it performs close to realtime (around 30fps). When i change the 3d view to rendered it still manages to "start" rendering 2-3 frames per second in the viewport.

Is there a way to have that as well when exporting the animation? -at least for the rendering of non-final animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable Persistent Data in Properties Editor > Render tab > Performance panel.

[Blender Manual — Persistent Data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#final-render)

Comment: THANK YOU. That's so much better now. :)

Comment: Glad I could help!